# Extract iframe src value when iframe is rendering as a string

Tags: javascript

I have an iframe printing as a string:

```
  src="https://open.spotify.com/embed/playlist/0lzAOQqIopBHburyOt82lC"
  width="300"
  height="380"
  frameborder="0"
  allowtransparency="true"
  allow="encrypted-media"
></iframe>;
```

How can I extract the `src` value from the string and omit every other value?

Comment: Your string is as follows yes?  `<iframe src="https://open.spotify.com/embed/playlist/0lzAOQqIopBHburyOt82lC" width="300" height="380" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>`

Comment: @dalelandry Correct

Comment: You're looking for `src="https://open.spotify.com/embed/playlist/0lzAOQqIopBHburyOt82lC"` ? or just the URL? And do you want it to be in the iframe?

Answer (score 0):

Came up with a solution:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (linkUrl) {
      // parse iframe url
      let data = `${linkUrl}`;

      let parser = new DOMParser();

      let parsedIframe = parser.parseFromString(data, "text/html");
      let iFrame = parsedIframe.getElementsByTagName("iframe");

      // Read URL:
      let src = iFrame[0].src;
      console.log("SRC", src);
      setIframeUrl(src);

      // Parse URL:
      let match = src.match(/\/(\d+)\//);
      let digits = match ? match[1] : null;
      console.log("DIGITS", digits);
    }
  }, [linkUrl]);
```